# How do I replace the standard language switcher with flags? Magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento2, multistore, language, stores, switcher

I am migrating my Magento 1.9 store to Magento 2.1.

I am still quite new in Magento 2.1 and I can't seem to find some things.

Any guidelines on how to replace the textual store switcher with flags?

Answer (score 12):

I was struggling with the same problem for some time and finally managed to solve it. Maybe you already solved it by now, but it can definitely be useful for others.

---

## Summary

*The needed code can be found at the end of this post.*

1. create all missing folders on this path: `/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/{theme_dir}/Magento_Store/templates/switch`
2. copy the code of `language.phtml` and add it to this folder
3. go to file `/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/{theme_dir}/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`.
    - If it doesn't exist, copy it from `/var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`
4. add the line `<css src="css/languageSwitcher.css"/>`
5. copy the code of `languageSwitcher.css` and add it to folder `/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{name}/web/css`
6. create folder `/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{name}/web/images/flags` and add flags with naming convention `flag_{country_ID}.png` e.g. `flag_en.png`. All images need to have the same resolution.
7. Recompile...haven't figured out yet if you also need to flush the cache...just do trial and error.

---

## Extended explanation and extra information

First, you need to find, which template is responsible for the language switcher. Therefore, head to the admin-site of your Magento installation, go to **`Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes`**. Now reload the page of your store and you will see a lot of red boxes with names in it. The box which contains the drop-down language-switcher has a path like:

`/var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/view/frontend/templates/switch/languages.phtml`.

What you want to do is to create your own template and add the changes you want. Therefore, **NEVER** change the aforementioned template. It is not safe because every Magento update will overwrite the changes (and maybe something else will do as well....). The recommended way is:

Copy the template to the path:

`/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{name}/{vendor_name}_{module_name}/templates/{path_to_template}/template.phtml`.

{namespace} = the module's namespace (e.g. your company/domain/...)
{name} = name of the module
{vendor_name} = the name of the vendor, which provided the template
{module_name} = the module in which the template lies
{path_to_template} = the path to the right of `templates`

In our case, this results to:

`/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{name}/Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml`

Now, this should already work, if you make some changes to the copy, they should appear on the site.

---

**CSS** 
In my solution I also used a css file to style the template. Therefore we need to add the path to the `default_head_blocks.xml`. The default file lies in `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

To make changes to this file, copy it to your corresponding folder and add the path to the css file. Path:

`/var/www/magento/app/code/{theme_dir}/{Magento_Theme}/view/frontend/layout`

Therein you can also add extra *.js files and other sources.... add this line to the end of default_head_blocks.xml (but inside the `<head>` tags): `<css src="css/languageSwitcher.css"/>`.

Navigate to the folder `/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{name}/web/css` and add the `languageSwitcher.css`.

Next, head to `.../web/images` and create the folder `flags`. Add images to the folder with the naming convention: `flag_{country_ID}.png`. E.g. for English use `flag_en.png`. They all need to have the same resolution.

---

## Code (languages.phtml & languageSwitcher.css)

**languages.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Language switcher template
 */
?>

<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
    <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php if ($_lang->getCode() != 'default'): ?>
        <a class="lang-flag" href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl() . '?___store=' . $_lang->getCode();?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/flag_' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt="<?php echo 'could not find image for ' . $_lang->getName() ?>"/></a>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

**languageSwitcher.css**

```
.langs-wrapper {
    height: 15px;
}
 
.lang-flag {
    width: 55px;
    height: 32.5px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
 
.lang-flag:hover {
    border: 2.5px solid #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in your theme `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Language switcher template
 */
if (count($this->getStores())) { ?>
<div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang) { ?>
        <a class="lang-flag" href="#" data-post='<?php echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>'><img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt="<?php echo $_lang->getName(); ?>" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

This will make the language-switch persist using a session rather than just switch language on the specific page and discard it on next.

Answer (score 0):

You can put  below code in your template file.

[image]

Add your Country Flag Images inside “flag” directory in skin/[your_theme]/images/folder and name it as the store view code.